# Validate if active public key and owner public key is correct

Tags: keys, public-key

How do i validate if user entered correct active public and owner public key (e.g. length, no forbidden characters entered) using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [eosjs-ecc](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc) library to validate keys in JavaScript:

```
const ecc = require('eosjs-ecc')

const pubkey = 'EOS7rHHE6Gp11zLdTio5xCcGd8KtnDcDYNRC5595hfeKTizePAKZP'
const wif = '5HzevvzwHzcQAZiMSJpZapj87QwtBrtPAwXc4yGwHowLhbujKbg'

console.log(ecc.isValidPublic(pubkey)) // true
console.log(ecc.isValidPrivate(wif)) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would just convert the private key to public with `ecc.privateToPublic` then compare the result to your `pubkey` variable.